# JWT e Identity MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, jwt

Salve galera,

Estou procurando como utilizar os dois (JWT com Identity MVC 5), mas não encontro nada sobre isso, só encontrei para o Identity .Net Core 2, esse não serve pra mim porque a aplicação já foi criada em MVC 5. Alguém sabe se isso é possível? Ou realmente só da no .Net core 2?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta, caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida ta aqui:

[jwt + mvc identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization)